# Generic Format DateTime for MySQL and Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, mariadb

I want to cast a string to **UTC** date. But with environments, database varies and code needs to be changed accordingly as below.

```
if env1
//mysql
insert into table values (STR_TO_DATE('datetime','%%m/%%d/%%Y %%H:%%i:%%s'))
else
//oracle
insert into table values (to_date('%s', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

So, Is there a way to handle this generic? by just generating UTC date in code itself and then inserting in database accordingly with any date exception in database?

Comment: Are you using `JDBC` to connect to the database? And by UTC do you mean the `long` value?

Comment: Yes JDBC. UTC Datetime format

Comment: The title and body say MySQL but you have tagged "mariadb"; which is it?

Comment: If that is the only difference between MySQL and Oracle that you have hit, it is a miracle.  There are maaaaaaaaany diffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PreparedStatement` has three methods to use to set dates: [setDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-), [setTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTime-int-java.sql.Time-) and [setTimestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-).
You can use either of them that suits you best.

To get the `PreparedStatement` object, call `.prepareStatement("your sql query")` on your connection ojbect.

In your case, your query will be `"insert into table values (?)"`

Answer (score 1):

Within the databases, you can use the same `INSERT` statement if you use a `TIMESTAMP` literal ([MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html), [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref367)):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf5b0/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value DATE );

INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( TIMESTAMP '2018-03-23 11:12:00' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf5b0/1/0)**:

```
|                VALUE |
|----------------------|
| 2018-03-23T11:12:00Z |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d10b8/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value TIMESTAMP );

INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( TIMESTAMP '2018-03-23 11:12:00' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d10b8/1/0)**:

```
|                value |
|----------------------|
| 2018-03-23T11:12:00Z |
```